# Institution logo in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know a little bit about TIKZ, but I would like help to do or how to start to build the logo of the institution in which I study.

If it is all the logo it would be great, if not, that it is only the logo in green and red above.

[image]

Comment: While possible, including something like this in your document using solely `tikz` would probably be more trouble than it's worth. I'd recommend just using something like [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) to redesign the logo and then importing it using the `graphicx` package. Last case scenario just simply use the image file that you used in this question.

Comment: Doesn't your institution provide this logo as a PDF your an include? If not, might be an idea to recommend them to provide one.

Comment: I recommend following @daleif advice. I have an experience of spending hours on the logo and they told me that it was not ok for a millimetric difference in the font... better not to play with official logos ;-)

Comment: @Rmano our is actually also available as a font, so via font forge you can convert it into svg and grap that data for tikz. That is how I got a tikz version of our very intrinsic university seal

Comment: In my opinion, what is asked is against the trademark laws. This question should be deleted.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Some institutions have rules about using their logos, which are not technically trademarks, but they may be protected by their owner. One has to check with the institution to see whether the usage is allowed. For instance, I'm allowed to use my university/department logo for official purposes, but students are not allowed to use it on their thesis frontispiece.

Comment: @egreg See here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8762/difference-between-poor-answer-and-answer-does-not-attempt-answering-the-ques. Ciao!

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's where I saw you commented. ;-)

Comment: @egreg As we don't know the rules of that institution, I presume it is not allowed :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just because we shouldn't, doesn't mean we can't ;)

```
\newlength\w\setlength\w{8.5mm}
\documentclass[border=.5\w]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{raleway}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{359730}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{c90c10}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{1d1d1d}
\tikzset{grid/.style = {minimum width=\w, minimum height=\w, rounded corners={#1}}}
\newcommand{\square}[2]{\node[fill=green,grid={.1\w}] at (#1,#2){};}
\renewcommand{\circle}[2]{\node[fill=red,grid={.5\w}] at (#1,#2){};}
\def\bigstyle{\fontsize{12mm}{11mm}\bfseries\selectfont\centering}
\def\medstyle{\fontsize{8mm}{10mm}\selectfont\centering}
\begin{document}
\color{black}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \circle{-1}{4}\square{0}{4}\square{+1}{4}
  \square{-1}{3}\square{0}{3}
  \square{-1}{2}\square{0}{2}\square{+1}{2}
  \square{-1}{1}\square{0}{1}
  \node[fill=green,minimum width=9\w,minimum height=0.5mm,inner sep=0pt] at (0,-3.4){};
  \node at (0,-1) {\parbox{7cm}{\bigstyle{INSTITUTO\\FEDERAL}}};
  \node at (0,-2.7) {\parbox{7cm}{\medstyle{Goiano}}};
  \node at (0,-4.5) {\parbox{7cm}{\medstyle{Campus\\Rio Verde}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can't match the font exactly. The closest I found was [raleway](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/raleway/). The spacing also needs to be more precise.

[image]

Comment: Your definitions of \circle and \square look very similar; could you explain why they do different things?

Comment: Sure. They have different `\fill` colours, of course. Then I used a custom tikz style called `grid`, which accepts one argument, and applies it to the `rounded corners` radius. Since I set the `minimum height` and `minimum width` both to `\w`, then a radius of `0.5\w` will make a circle, while `0.1\w` will round just the corners a bit. It's a bit of a hack.

Comment: I see, so circles are just squares with very rounded corners. Thanks!

Comment: We should not because it is against trademark laws.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I seriously doubt it is against the law to just (attempt to) recreate any logo/trademark for your own personal amusement (or skill development, or to see if it is possible with a certain toolbox). By extension, helping someone in these regards is also permissible. Surely if the OP is maleficent, they could simply import the original logo as a picture and use that instead, not bothering with tikz.